# Can't complie .class file with rmic , class not file

Tags: java, rmi, rmic

Well i decided to create RMI but faced with one problem. 
i put CLASSPATH= (to my jdk) then i decided to make Stub with rmic.
I wrote:
 1. **rmic -classpath "D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin\rmi\app" AddServer -d
    D:\workspace**

where i got such message:
**error: File D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin\rmi\app\AddServer.class does not contai
n type AddServer as expected, but type rmi.app.AddServer. Please remove the file
, or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the class path.
error: Class AddServer not found.
2 errors**

Comment: Then i got the problem:rmic -classpath "D:\workspace\Rmi.example\b
in\rmi.app" AddServer -d D:\workspace
error: Class AddServer not found.
1 error

Answer (score 1):

```
rmic -classpath "D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin" rmi.app.AddServer -d D:\workspace
```

**BUT:** Don't use 'rmic' at all. It hasn't been required for about ten years. Read the preamble to UnicastRemoteObject. Basically, as long as you provide a port number when constructing/exporting your remote objects, even zero, a dynamic stub can be generated instead at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your class AppServer is in rmi.app package? Then your classpath must be D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin, not D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin\rmi\app

Comment: yeah i have rmi.app package

Comment: rmic -classpath D:\workspace\RMIexample\bin AddServer -d D:\workspa
ce
error: Class AddServer not found.
1 error

Comment: Is your project directory name RMIexample or RMI.example? Also, the class name must be rmi.app.AddServer

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to run rmic from the base directory where your package starts. For example: `rmic -classpath "D:\workspace\Rmi.example\bin\" rmi.app.AddServer -d D:\workspace`